# Translate this car plate image into text

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, tesseract, python-tesseract

I have a picture:
[image: pic to be cropped]

I want to turn the car plate into text.

After I do crop of the plates with `python-opencv`:
[image: cropped]

`pytesseract.image_to_string(bbox, lang='eng', config='--psm 6')` returns me: `"TH`

My code for cropping:

```
coordinates = [[0.6703869047619048, 0.39855072463768115],
               [0.7672123015873016, 0.39855072463768115],
               [0.7672123015873016, 0.47681159420289854],
               [0.6703869047619048, 0.47681159420289854],
               [0.6703869047619048, 0.39855072463768115]]
img = cv.imread(pic)
height, width, channels = img.shape
bbox_coordinates = [[int(coordinate[0] * width), int(coordinate[1] * height)] for coordinate in coordinates]
```

Then I turn it for better quality into greyscale:
`bbox = cv.cvtColor(bbox, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)`

[image: cropped greyscale]

`pytesseract.image_to_string(bbox, lang='eng', config='--psm 6')` returns: `To`

Is there a way to get `WA 6728 M`? (with or without usage of `pytesseract 4`)

Comment: Couldn't understand what you're asking here, pytesseract doesn't read the plates well?

Comment: @hodisr I need to get string  `WA 6728 M` from the photo with plate, but `pytesseract` gives wrong results with described in the question approach

Comment: Got it, well it's based on Google’s Tesseract-OCR Engine so it isn't always gets the right answer, btw for common knowledge grey-scaling the img might look better in quality for the human eye but dont forget the model views the image in all three colors so grey-scaling it means less data for the inference.

Comment: checkout https://cvisiondemy.com/license-plate-detection-with-opencv-and-python/

Comment: The [openalpr](https://github.com/openalpr/openalpr) library seems great for your application. It uses OpenCV and Tesseract OCR

Comment: @nathancy `IMPORTANT: you cannot use this package without a product license.`  https://pypi.org/project/openalpr/

Comment: Oh sorry didn't know! Thanks!

Comment: @nathancy np, thank you for trying to help

Answer (score 0):

I try this picture:
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLgiF.jpg

```
def process_image(image):
    pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:\\Users\\abenhari\\AppData\\Local\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe'
    img = Image.open(image)
    img = img.convert('L')
    pix = img.load()
    plt.imshow(img)
    plt.show()
    return pytesseract.image_to_string(img)

print(process_image("plat1.jpg"))
```